# How can use ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor and spring.profiles.group?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.2 and tried to use spring.profiles.group in my property files like:

application.yaml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      local: core
```

application-core.yaml

```
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local

...
```

but the "group" property is not found.
As I checked, it is using deprecated ConfigFileApplicationListener instead of ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.

Why it uses legacy spring profile processing even though version of spring is upper 2.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

`application-core.yaml` doesn't require the following:

```yaml
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
```

This is what is needed:

`application.yaml`:

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      local: core
```

`application-core.yaml`

```yaml
...
```